# How to read configuration in a class library located in a different project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have my database related stuff in another project which is a class library. I would like to specify the connection string in my `config.json` file. However, I couldnt find out how to read the configuration. Inside the static constructor of my `SessionFactory` I call:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("config.json");
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

However, I get an exception that the config file is not found since it's being searched in the executed application (which is a separate project). I tried to set the base path but no luck with that as well.

How do I read the config file in class library in a separate project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as when previously using app/web.config.  The configuration specific to your currently executing context should be local.  If you want access to settings specified for a different project, you should instead add those settings to your current project's configuration.

For example, for the structure;

```
src
    DataProject
        config.json
    ApplicationProject
        config.json
```

Because you are executing `ApplicationProject`, all configuration needs to be specified in `ApplicationProject\config.json`, and then made available later to `DataProject` via dependency injection or otherwise.  `DataProject\config.json` is irrelevant, because `DataProject` will not be the executing assembly.

If you have configuration values in `DataProject\config.json` that are neccessary when executing `ApplicationProject`, then you should copy those values into `ApplicationProject\config.json`.

Comment: I am trying to reach the class library's config from the class library itself. But then how do I make the configuration global ?

Comment: That class library is being executed by another project - which is the project where the config needs to be defined.